# InDesign Scripting: Need to export INDD file as INX (INDX)

Tags: javascript, export, adobe-indesign

I'm working with InDesign CS4 and CS3.
Both need to export their files down to CS2.
I'd like to use a .jsx code snippet to export to INDX, but I can't seem to do-so with the ExportFormat."formatName" JS code. Doesn't look like Adobe supports exporting to INDX from javascript - perhaps using a plugin (but that's a lot of overhead for a simple export).

Also, I'll need to edit the .indx file (which is just XML) to change the file version node so CS2 can read the exported file.

These layouts are pretty simple, minimal layers, no effects, so I'm not too concerned about the downsave.

What I'm really screwed up on is this:

How can I export from InDesign (CS3/CS4) to indx using JavaScript scripting?

Answer (score 0):

```
<docObject>.exportFile(ExportFormat.indesignInterchange, <fileObject>)
```